# JSF passthrough elements jsf:action javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, passthrough-elements

I'm using JSF 2.2 passthrough elements and I'd like to call both functions, `jsf:action` and `jsf:onclick`. I tryed a lot of ways to do it and none worked for me.

The closest approach I got, was this way:

**HTML**

```
<form jsf:id="frmNavigation">    
   <a jsf:id="btnHome"  jsf:action="#{bean.action()}" jsf:onclick="clickHome">
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="frmRedirect:frmNewHomeRedirect"/>
   </a>
   [...]
</form>
```

**JS**

```
  function clickHome(){
  document.getElementById("frmRedirect:frmNavigation:btnHome").addClass("metro-btn-red");

  document.getElementById("frmRedirect:frmNavigation:btnCadCli").removeClass("metro-btn-red");
  document.getElementById("frmRedirect:frmNavigation:btnModel1").removeClass("metro-btn-red");
  document.getElementById("frmRedirect:frmNavigation:btnModel2").removeClass("metro-btn-red");
}
```

***Note*** My JS it's in the HTML page, but either in external JS it didn't worked. 
The id related in the JS appers to be correct. I checked the DOM output.
I also tryed to invoke click function in JS code. It didn't worked. Either tryed the HTML onclick, but this one erases the Mojarra click event ( `jsf:action` ).
I found another anwser in this forum 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/211593/JSF/java/Calling-backingBean-method-javascripthttp://www.coderanch.com/t/211593/JSF/java/Calling-backingBean-method-javascript
 Guess what, it didn't worked too '_'.

I'm missing something which I can't figure.

I was thinking if there is a way to call my action from JS. Is there an way to do that without composing a new element?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update

Trying the same in a new project:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

  <head jsf:id="head">
    <title>Facelet Title</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <style type="text/css">

      .btn{
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: solid 2px #303030;
        color: #303030;
      }
      .btn-red{
        background-color: #C30563;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function clickMe() {
        document.getElementById("btn").addClass("btn-red");
      }

    </script>

  </head>
  <body jsf:id="body">

    <form jsf:id="frm" jsf:prependId="false">

     <a jsf:id="btn"  type="submit" jsf:value="Click me" jsf:action="#{cbMain.doSomething()}" jsf:onclick="clickMe()" class="btn">
       <f:ajax execute="@form" render="frmRender"/>
    </a>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Back Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("cbMain")
@SessionScoped
public class TesteBean implements Serializable{

  private int i = 0;

  public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println( i++ );
  }

}
```

And this is the generated lines in **DOM**:

```
<a id="btn" href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'clickMe()','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'action\',\'@form\',\'frmRender\')');return false" type="submit" class="btn">Click me</a>
```

It also didn't worked for me in a new and clean project.

Answer (score 0):

In basic HTML, the `onclick` attribute must represent a JavaScript expression. You've however only specified the function name. This causes a JS problem. It's as if you're doing

```
<script>clickHome;</script>
```

Add parentheses to make it a true expression:

```
<a ... jsf:onclick="clickHome()">
```

This is not a JSF related problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when trying the same in basic HTML.

```
<a ... onclick="clickHome">
```

See also the JSF-generated HTML output via rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser. In future questions try to do the same in basic HTML instead. JSF is in the context of this question "just" a HTML code generator. It's ultimately yourself who's responsible that it generates the right HTML output.

Comment: I alredy tryed that but, either, the JS and the JSF actions doesn't works.

Comment: Then the problem is not visible in the information provided so far. When I copypaste your code into a completely empty JSF project with everything set to default and most recent versions, then it works just for me after having fixed the mistake as per the above answer. Both the JS function and the bean action gets invoked.